# Mostrar archivos alojados en base de datos mysql -PHP

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Logré que el archivo sease PDF, img, etc. se cargue en la BD, pero cuando quiero mostrarlo me arroja NOT FOUND, no he logrado encontrar donde tengo el error. A lo que veo, en la URL me muestra el archivo como si lo tuviera en local. De hecho si coloco el archivo en la ruta que esta en la URL si lo muestra la pagina. Pero lo muestra desde mi carpeta local y no desde la base de datos.
Asi me lo muestra la URL;
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mi codigo para mostrarlo es:**

```
<table width="80%" border="1">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="4">CARGAs...<label><a href="admin.php">subir mas...</a></label></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Nombre</td>
    <td>Tipo</td>
    <td>tamaño(KB)</td>
    <td>ver</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
 $sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_uploads";
 $result_set=mysqli_query($link,$sql);
 while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result_set))
 {
  ?>
  
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['file'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['type'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['size'] ?></td>


        <td><a href="uploads/<?php echo $row['file'] ?>" target="_blank">view file</a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
 }
 ?>
    </table>
```

Y si están en la BD
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También dejo el código para el upload del archivo

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
{    
     
 $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
 $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
 $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
 $folder="C:/wamp64/uploads/";
 

 $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
 $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
 
 $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
 
 if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
 { 

  $sql="INSERT INTO tbl_uploads(file,type,size) VALUES('$final_file','$file_type','$new_size')";
  mysqli_query($link,$sql);
  ?>
```

ADICIONAL:
**me genera los TMP en la ruta: C:/wamp64/uploads/**
Espero me puedan orientar

Comment: ¿Puede ser que haya algún archivo tipo .htaccess que está tocando las URLs?

Comment: Tengo duda en la línea: 
 a href= uploads /  creo que por ahi va el error.

Comment: No, no tengo ningun .htaccess, de hecho lo pensé, pero no tengo ninguno.

Comment: No estás moviendo los archivos a la ruta correcta: `$folder="C:/wamp64/uploads/";`. Debería ser algo como `$folder="C:/wamp64/ManualesTIENDA/Departamentos/uploads/";`

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente como indicó Triby, la ruta la tenía mal, error mio.

En la línea 8
$folder="C:/wamp64/uploads/";
esta ruta la tenia incorrecta, ya que ahi no tenia los archivos PDF guardados. Los tenia dentro de otra carpeta y por eso nunca me los mostraba.
Realicé el cambio de la ruta para esa carpeta y ya me mostró correctamente todo.

Comment: Ya edité la respuesta, gracias BetaM